# Cannot access tomcat manager or any other default tomcat app when running tomcat in docker

Tags: docker, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat9

I am trying to access tomcat manager app from host. The port publishing is successfull but when trying to access tomcat manager I get 404 error.

This is the command used to launch the tomcat :

```
docker container run -p 8010:8080 --name mytomcat tomcat:9.0
```

and trying to access it by url :

```
http://localhost:8010/manager
```

From the logs I can confirm that tomcat is running, and I can access it from host system, but when accessing the manager app, 404 is received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that all default tomcat apps have been removed from the `webapps` directory for all tomcat images starting with Tomcat version 7.
All apps have been moved to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist` directory so that they are not launched by default. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/pull/181).

If you still want to access those default apps you can copy them back to the webapps directory, if you wish:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0
RUN mv /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist/* /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

or copy only the apps that you want. Also you will have to edit tomcat configuration files to not get 403 when accessing those apps.