# Tomcat docker container: `manager` not found in webapp directory

Tags: docker, jenkins, tomcat

I'm trying to configure automatic app deployment to Tomcat server using Jenkins. Tomcat runs as a docker container:

```
$ docker run --rm --name tomcat tomcat
```

I've configured Jenkins build, but it fails at deployment step. Here is what's in Output:

> org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Tomcat_sample_app_autodeploy/sample.war]
>
> [stack trace here]
>
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://tomcat:8080/manager/text/list

[Here is described](https://www.programmersought.com/article/84824959233/) that two things could possibly cause that problem and one of these is: "manager" not present in `webapps` folder. And indeed `webapp` directory in my container looks empty:

[image]

At the same time I can see in many tutorials that this manager is available out-of-the-box with Tomcat.

Has something changed in that matter? Do I need to somehow configure that `manager` manually?

Comment: If you are using the [Docker Official Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat), the default apps where moved to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps.dist` (cf. the _"How to use this image"_ section).

Comment: So what should I do now? Can I move contents of `webapps.dist` to `webapps`? On a page you've linked there is something about "making it easy to re-enable", but nothing about what that means

Comment: Ok, found it, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61972820) I can move it

Comment: You can move it or create a `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml` descriptor.