# Running a docker container in the same network as already running container

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm testing to see if two containers (tomcat and busybox) in a same network 'myNetwork' are able to communicate with each other.

I followed the steps:

1. Create a network, 'myNetwork'

   `docker network create -d bridge myNetwork`
2. Run a 'myTomcat' container in 'myNetwork'

   `docker run -it --name myTomcat --net=myNetwork tomcat`
3. Run a 'busybox' container in the same network as 'myTomcat' network. i.e 'myNetwork'

   `docker run -it --net=container:myTomcat busybox`
4. Test if tomcat container is accessible from busybox container using wget command

   `docker container exec -it {busybox_container_id}`

   `/# wget localhost:8080`

Here I I got an error `wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404`

I wonder why I can't connect to tomcat container from busybox container even though I configured both containers in the same network.
So I inspected by doing:

```
    docker network inspect myNetwork
[
  {
    "Name": "myNetwork",
...
    "Containers": {
      "43ba4d7ae27753f8085f5697cf6afc4eb872dbdbd2cf18138e3c6e3f90d54d15":{
        "Name": "myTomcat",
        "EndpointID":"03a98...",
...
        "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    }
 }
]
 
    docker inspect {tomcat_container_id}
[
...
  "Networks": {
    "myNetwork": {
      "NetworkID": "54bf...",
      ...
      "Gateway": "172.20.0.1",
      "IPAddress": "172.20.0.2"
      ...
    }
...
]
    docker inspect {busybox_container_id}
[
...
  "NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    ...
    "Networks": {}
  }
...
]
```

It seems tomcat is in 'myNetwork', but inspecting busybox container doesn't seem to show any network information. I'd appreciate for any help

Comment: How do you connect from `busybox` to `tomcat`? Via name or IP?

Comment: If you're getting an HTTP 404 error, you've connected successfully, and possibly the problem is that you haven't loaded any `.war` files into Tomcat.  This having been said, the `--net=container:...` construction is really unusual; why this particular setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze  You're right. After I created index.html inside tomcat container's $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.html,  I was able to 'wget localhost:8080' from busybox container and download index.html file. I'm trying `--net=container:...` command just for learning purposes, while I'm learning some basic networking command in docker. Thank you.

Comment: @Saeed My test case assumes that both `busybox` and `tomcat` containers are in the same network. So you might be able to connect to a running `tomcat` server by simply `localhost:8080`, or `myTomcat:8080` as AymDev answered.

Comment: Also Default tomcat webapps directory has been moved to webapps.dist starting with Tomcat version 7, preventing the tomcat default page loading up as soon as the tomcat instance started.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972819/cannot-access-tomcat-manager-or-any-other-default-tomcat-app-when-running-tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Using `localhost` always point to the current machine. Using it in a Docker container targets the *current container*.

If you need your containers to communicate *in a Docker network* you can make use of the embedded DNS server by using **container names** as **host names**. As you named your **Tomcat** container `myTomcat` you should be able to do:

```sh
wget myTomcat:8080
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found that my `HTTP 404 error` was not because I couldn't access the tomcat server, but because the running tomcat server simply didn't have a default index.html page configured in the `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT` directory. After creating index.html inside the tomcat container's directory, I was able to `wget myTomcat:8080` from `busybox` container. And `wget localhost:8080` also worked fine, because both containers are in the same network, I think.

Comment: @lophih Oh maybe that's because of the way you defined the network of the busybox container. I never used `--net=container:...`, not even `--net` alone. That's not very common. I guess that this syntax acts like host networking between containers because there is no way that `localhost` points to another container except if it inherited its network interfaces.
If you want to get a more *"standard"* setup you could add the busybox container to the network as you did for the Tomcat one, then I think you'll be able to test that `localhost:8080` won't work but `myTomcat:8080` will.